# CSS and HTML UI issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am learning CSS and Jquery.. So now its a learning curve for me as I am newbie in these..
Here as per the code below, when the user clicks on the li tag the checkbox gets activated as well as the color also changes. And when the user clicks on the links it goes to the specified location. But I want the link to be directed to the specifed location when the user clicks on the any part of li  also. it would be great if this can be done using CSS..Any inputs..?? Please help.

```
<html>
    <head>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://editor.webyana.com/javascripts/client_scripts/potential/jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
            jQuery(function($) {

            $("li.gc").click(function() {

            $("li.gc").css({
            'background-color': '#FFFFFF'
            });

            $(this).css({
            'background-color': '#FDF7C2'
            });
            $("li.gc input[type=checkbox]").attr("checked", false);


            $(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").attr("checked", true);

            });
            }); 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li class="gc ">

                <div>
                    <input type="checkbox"/>
                    <a href="http://www.google.com">Link1</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="gc">
                <div>

                    <input type="checkbox"/>
                    <a href="http://www.google.com">Link2</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just curious, why are you wanting to open links with a checkbox? I cant see the UI implementation, but this seems like a confusing concept for the users...

Answer (score 1):

Under your `.attr("checked", true);` line, add this:

```
window.location = $(this).find('a')[0].href;
```

---

After testing, I realised that you need to stop the `.click()` if it's on the checkbox, so also add:

```
$("li.gc input").click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Yes, it can. I didn't do so because it didn't seem to fit with your code. I'll update my answer.

Comment: The right side of what? You're not giving enough information on what you're actually trying to do here. Describe it from the start.

Comment: So the only problem with the code you pasted in your question in the first place is that the link does not "fill the line"? Everything else is ok?

Comment: yes.. You are right.. it would be great if anybody could give any thoughts on this..

Comment: Anybody Please help on the above question.

Comment: @user662503: Sorry, I forgot about this. Do you still need help? Has anything changed?